Why is switching desktops in Windows 11 on a Surface Pro 4 so slow?
My Surface Pro works like a molasses with a i7 processor it lags when switching virtual desktops.
Do anyone know a fix to this? I may simply not use virtual desktops but folks from Microsoft should know it is the real issue.
Surface Pro 4 with 16gb and i7 It doesnt matter how much programs. Switching animation lag. I compared to macOS sleek animations. Windows just lags.
